# can't change <a> color and background color of an ID (#sidebar) with a class (.selected)

Tags: html, css, colors, background-color

I'm new at HTML and CSS, and I doing my first project and already facing a problem.

Well I've created an ID named sidebar so I can have an sub-menu at the left side of the page, and a class named selected which would idenify the actual selected sub menu.

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <h2>Sub Menu</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="selected">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then at my css "style.css"

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
}
            /*SIDE MENU*/
#sidebar ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#sidebar ul li { 
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#sidebar ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #385900;
    background: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #E6E7E9;
    color: #DA7910;
}
```

This works fine and did what I need;

The problem occurs when I try to change Color and Background-color of the selected sub menu. The .selectd class isn't able to apply the color change over the #sidebar ID, only Font-weight and font-size worked as I expected.

```
.selected {
    color:white;
    background-color:#385900;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? what is missing me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In CSS, the most specific selector rules "win". See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meyxXr for a working example of what you want. See also this post for a good explanation: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Thanks, I was trying  .selected a {};  #sidebar .selected a {}, and it could not work ofcourse.  Thanks I know understood better  the nesting procedure, thanks again

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 2):

It's time you learn one of the advance topic of CSS called [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Instead of only `.selected` use `#sidebar ul li a.selected` to increase the specificity of the CSS selector.